# iOS simulator shows flickering lines

Tags: ios, opengl-es, lines, glkit

In my app, I draw a series of points (stars) and then a series of lines (constellation figures) but the lines are flickering on the simulator and when I run the app on my iPhone there are no lines at all. Any ideas?

(I'm running OpenGL 2.0 ES in a GLKView under a GLKViewController.)

Edit: Here is the drawing code where I use a custom shader for the stars but I don't really need it for the lines. Not sure how to return to a default shader. (I've tried glUseProgram(0); which is supposed to work but it makes no difference.)

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    // Drawing code
    //    NSLog(@"GBStarField drawRect invoked!");

    /*********************************/
    // Draw all stars
    /*********************************/

    // Clear the framebuffer
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Calculate OpenGL to GLKit View coordinate transformation

    // Calculate perspective transformation
    float aspect = fabsf(self.bounds.size.width / self.bounds.size.height);
    GLKMatrix4 projectionMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakePerspective(GLKMathDegreesToRadians(90.0f), aspect, 0.0f, 10.0f);

    self.effect.transform.projectionMatrix = projectionMatrix;

    // Calculate translation transformation
#ifdef USE_RA_DEC
    GLKMatrix4 modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakeTranslation(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
#else
    GLKMatrix4 modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakeTranslation(0.0f, 0.0f, -2.0f);
#endif

    // Calculate rotation transformation
    // remember the right hand rule for rotation vector
    modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4Rotate(modelViewMatrix, GLKMathDegreesToRadians(rotation/10), 0, 1, 0);
    //modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4Rotate(modelViewMatrix, GLKMathDegreesToRadians(-90), 0, 0, 1); // polaris
    //modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4Rotate(modelViewMatrix, GLKMathDegreesToRadians(180-279.2346), 0, 1, 0); // vega
    //modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4Rotate(modelViewMatrix, GLKMathDegreesToRadians(-38.783692), 0, 0, 1); // vega
    //modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4Rotate(modelViewMatrix, GLKMathDegreesToRadians(180-78.63447), 0, 1, 0); // rigel
    //modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4Rotate(modelViewMatrix, GLKMathDegreesToRadians(8.20164), 0, 0, 1); // rigel

    self.effect.transform.modelviewMatrix = modelViewMatrix;

    [self.effect prepareToDraw];

    // Get uniform locations (must be after linking)
    GLint u_projectionMatrixLocation;
    u_projectionMatrixLocation = glGetUniformLocation(programBrightStar, (const GLchar*) "u_projectionMatrix");
    GLint u_modelViewMatrixLocation;
    u_modelViewMatrixLocation = glGetUniformLocation(programBrightStar, (const GLchar*) "u_modelViewMatrix");

    // Get attribute locations (must be after linking)
    GLint a_positionLocation;
    a_positionLocation =  glGetAttribLocation(programBrightStar, (const GLchar*) "a_position");
    GLint a_colorLocation;
    a_colorLocation =  glGetAttribLocation(programBrightStar, (const GLchar*) "a_color");
    GLint a_pointsizeLocation;
    a_pointsizeLocation =  glGetAttribLocation(programBrightStar, (const GLchar*) "a_pointsize");

    // Working with the star buffers
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBuffer);
    glGetBufferParameteriv(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, GL_BUFFER_SIZE, &vertexBufferSize);
    //NSLog(@"vertexBufferSize/sizeof(Vertex) = %lu", vertexBufferSize/sizeof(Vertex));

    // Use custom vertex/fragment shader (must be after binging the buffers
    glUseProgram(programBrightStar);

    // Set uniforms for shader (must be after "glUseProgram")
    glUniformMatrix4fv(u_projectionMatrixLocation, 1, GL_FALSE, projectionMatrix.m);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(u_modelViewMatrixLocation, 1, GL_FALSE, modelViewMatrix.m);

    // Set attributes for shader (must be after "glUseProgram")
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(a_positionLocation);
    glVertexAttribPointer(a_positionLocation, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (const GLvoid *) offsetof(Vertex, Position));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(a_colorLocation);
    glVertexAttribPointer(a_colorLocation, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (const GLvoid *) offsetof(Vertex, Color));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(a_pointsizeLocation);
    glVertexAttribPointer(a_pointsizeLocation, 1, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (const GLvoid *) offsetof(Vertex, Pointsize));

    // Draw it as points defined by the vertex and index buffer data
    glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, vertexBufferSize/sizeof(Vertex));

    /*********************************/
    // Draw all constellations
    /*********************************/

    // Working with the constellation buffers
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, constellationVertexBuffer[0]);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, constellationIndexBuffer[0]);
    glGetBufferParameteriv(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, GL_BUFFER_SIZE, &indexBufferSize);
    //NSLog(@"indexBufferSize/sizeof(GLuint) = %lu", indexBufferSize/sizeof(GLuint));

    // Use custom vertex/fragment shader (must be after binging the buffers
    glUseProgram(programBrightStar);

    // Set uniforms for shader (must be after "glUseProgram")
    glUniformMatrix4fv(u_projectionMatrixLocation, 1, GL_FALSE, projectionMatrix.m);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(u_modelViewMatrixLocation, 1, GL_FALSE, modelViewMatrix.m);

    // Set attributes for shader (must be after "glUseProgram")
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(a_positionLocation);
    glVertexAttribPointer(a_positionLocation, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (const GLvoid *) offsetof(Vertex, Position));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(a_colorLocation);
    glVertexAttribPointer(a_colorLocation, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (const GLvoid *) offsetof(Vertex, Color));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(a_pointsizeLocation);
    glVertexAttribPointer(a_pointsizeLocation, 1, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (const GLvoid *) offsetof(Vertex, Pointsize));

    // Draw it as lines defined by the vertex and index buffer data
    glDrawElements(GL_LINES, indexBufferSize/sizeof(GLuint), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
}
```

Comment: Post your line drawing code. Sounds like you don't adapt the size of the lines to match (non-Retina) pixels on the screen or the distance of the line from the screen, therefore the line is too thin to light up even individual pixels. Consider what happens when you draw a line in 3D space from the camera forwards to infinity - eventually the line will vanish because at some point it's just too far away and thus too thin to be visible.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I added the code. The lines flicker even when I'm relatively close up. I've also tried using a line width of 2 and 3 but they still flicker. It seems that they all flickr at the same time as if the glDrawElements just doesn't happen sometimes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. It was my shader. I had a shader for stars that made circles from large square points. This was rejecting the lines as the image was rotated. I solved the problem by adding a second shader to draw the lines.